# Describe a Language Without the Noun for "Language"

Tags: существительные, other-languages, суффиксы, приветствия

In English it is rare to use the noun "language" when describing them.  It is most common to name the language as such:

- Engl **-ish**
- Span **-ish**
- French
- Russi **-an**
- Germ **-an**

Is it acceptable/common/comfortable to name these without the trailing word "язык?"
I.e. Английский without "язык"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is quite common in conversational speech:

- Он знает английский. = He knows English.
- Она предпочитает русский. = She prefers Russian.

Note that language names or nationalities are not capitalised in Russian. Neither are months or days or the week.

Comment: The capitalization is unexpected!  That is a very useful tip to pass along.

Comment: Another thing to notice is that at least for Russian the word the same as in English happens: `русский` is all: Russian the language, Russian the nationality (noun), Russian the belonging of a particular country adjective.

Comment: @OlegLobachev, the country-related adjective would be **российский**: российский флаг, гимн, etc. Only a handful of "national" adjectives have this distinction: латышский/латвийский, казахский/казахстанский (and other countries ending in -стан) and to some extent немецкий/германский. Have a look at this program that generates adjectives from country names: http://morpher.ru/adjectivizer/